How to handle the spaces in a command which is set in the Task Scheduler in batch file?
I am trying to set a task schedule to execute the command which installs the Python packages. However, the path of packages contains some space. I tried many way but could not get a good solution.
The batch file
@echo on
SCHTASKS /delete /tn "test" /f
SCHTASKS /create /tn "test" /sc ONCE /ST 00:00 /RL HIGHEST /tr "cmd.exe /k pip install "C:\test data\Python-Installer\numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl" "C:\test data\Python-Installer\opencv_python-4.5.4.60-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl""
SCHTASKS /run /tn "test"
pause

The result:
C:\Windows\system32>SCHTASKS /delete /tn "test" /f
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Windows\system32>SCHTASKS /create /tn "test" /sc ONCE /ST 00:00 /RL HIGHEST /tr "cmd.exe /k pip install "C:\test data\Python-Installer\numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl" "C:\test data\Python-Installer\opencv_python-4.5.4.60-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl""
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'data\Python-Installer\numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl C:\test'.
Type "SCHTASKS /CREATE /?" for usage.

C:\Windows\system32>SCHTASKS /run /tn "test"
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Windows\system32>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Please help me to "kill" the spaces in the code.
Any help is approciated

Frrst thing, remove cd /d "Python-Installer", which is not needed and is clearly displaying an error, (because it should have been CD /D "C:\test data\Python-Installer"). Then change @echo on on the next line to Echo On, (there is no such command as @echo). The leading character is only required if, at the time the line is parsed, echoing is not off. That of course means it would already be on
and means that there should never be a time when @Echo On exists as a command in a batch file. I would also advise that you remove the option to run the task with highest privileges.

@Compo thanks for your advice.
I edited the script.
Please show me how to take care of some spaces in the command SCHTASKS /create

This question is similar to: How do I deal with quote characters when using cmd.exe. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Well before you even do that, you should first of all use the correct syntax for the command(s), you want cmd.exe to run. The command line following /C, (the default), or /K should always be individually doublequoted. Additionally, it would be wise when running cmd.exe to use the /D option before /K.

@tripleee Thanks for your advice.
I already took a loot at your similar question above. However my case is quite different.

the cmd.exe command is an argument of another command.
the pip install command to be executed in cmd.exe also has the following arguments.
There are 2 arguments after pip install and they are separated by "space" as well.
If there is one package only, I could handle it. It means there is only one argument after pip install. But with 2 packages, I could not.


Please help me with this specified case.

@tripleee, that linked question is not similar, and the question does not require editing to prove otherwise. This question is not about handling nested doublequotes in cmd.exe, (which I have catered for in my previous comment). It is about handling nested doublequotes in schtasks.exe.

If you tried the solutions from the duplicate and none of them worked, please [edit] your question to show us what exactly you tried and how exactly it failed (no images). The quoting syntax doesn't depend on which command you are running, even in cmd

@triplee, those are not solutions to the problem reported. They are wise to be implemented, but will not solve the question at hand. The cmd.exe command is not being run here, so it itself cannot be an issue, yet.

@Compo I used to think so. But when I double quoted the command line, I could not execute it even with one argument after pip install.
With this command, the pip install could work. That's why I based on it to expand for 2 arguments after that.
SCHTASKS /create /tn "test" /sc ONCE /ST 00:00 /RL HIGHEST /tr "cmd.exe /k pip install """C:\test data\Python-Installer\numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl"""

@tripleee I don't think my question is duplicated from that post. thank you for your comment.

Did you try cmd.exe /S /k "pip install "C:\test data\Python-Installer\numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl" "C:\test data\Python-Installer\opencv_python-4.5.4.60-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl""? Did you try cmd.exe /k @"pip install "C:\test data\Python-Installer\numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl" "C:\test data\Python-Installer\opencv_python-4.5.4.60-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl""?

@DuyXike, the cmd.exe command should look more like this: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /D /S /K "@"C:\Users\DuyXike\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe" install "C:\test data\Python-Installer\numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl" "C:\test data\Python-Installer\opencv_python-4.5.4.60-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl"".

@tripleee I tried all before. the error is ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'install'.
Please take care that the cmd.exe is an argument of the SCHTASKS /create command.
I could execute the command as you suggested if it is a single command in the batch file.

@Compo I tried your suggestion, the code will be SCHTASKS /create /tn "test" /sc ONCE /ST 00:00 /RL HIGHEST /tr "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /D /S /K "@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install "C:\test data\Python-Installer\numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl" "C:\test data\Python-Installer\opencv_python-4.5.4.60-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl""" and the result is error ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'install'.

@DuyXike, I gave you the cmd.exe command only. You seem to have assumed I have given you an answer to your reported problem, which is incorrect. There is no point of getting the C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe command to work, until you have the individual components correct. You can then fix your issue by following the documentation advice. Spaces in file paths can be used by using two sets of quotes, one set for cmd.exe and one for schtasks.exe. The outer quotes for cmd.exe need to be double quotes; the inner quotes can be single quotes, ', or escaped double quotes, \".

All great advice from cmd-line all stars above. IMHO, you can eliminate a whole class of problems by not using spaces in your directory/folder names. Yes, I know C:\Program Files etc are baked in, but why self-inflict space related problems? (-;! Good luck.

As a follow up to my comments, here's my interpretation of the documentated quoting methodology, based around the correct cmd.exe parameters and arguments, and your submitted commands.
Echo On
%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /Delete /TN "test" /F
%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /Create /TN "test" /TR "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /S /K \"@\"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe\" install \"C:\test data\Python-Installer\numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl\" \"C:\test data\Python-Installer\opencv_python-4.5.4.60-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl\"\"" /SC ONCE /ST 00:00
%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /Run /TN "test"
Pause

You will note, that I have deliberately removed the /RL HIGHEST parameter and argument. I see no reason why you would be installing as SYSTEM, and in doing so, having a task with cmd.exe's /K option running in the background.

Thank you so much.
Your result works like a charm.
However, before receiving your result, I tried with this line, it also works but I do not understand clearly what the role of each double quote is. SCHTASKS /create /tn "peritec" /sc ONCE /ST 00:00 /tr "cmd.exe /k """pip install """C:\test data\Python-Installer\numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl""" """C:\test data\Python-Installer\opencv_python-4.5.4.60-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl""""

Thank you for the feedback on my solution @DuyXike. Regardless of whether escaping nested doublequotes with two additional doublequotes is working for you, what you've submitted in the comment above is not as robust, less efficient, and will take a little longer too. It is of course your task, and your choice how you decide to proceed.
